# IOS 13 and IOS 14 don't show keyboard on input focus

Tags: javascript, ios, angular

I have a problem that I can't fix.
The keyboard doesn't show on input.focus() on IOS 14 or 13 but it works well on IOS 12.
For elaboration in "input.focus()", input refers to DOM element in my case it refers to text field.
After some investigation, I found that Apple deprecated this [property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617967-keyboarddisplayrequiresuseractio) which leads to this problem.
Does anyone have a solution or know another method to be called as an alternative to the current one?

```
  <any>jQuery(document).on("changeFocus", function(event, element) {
    if (_wlContainerElemRef.nativeElement.contains(element)) {
      var elementPosition = focusableElements.indexOf(element);
      if (elementPosition < focusableElements.length - 1) {
        var nextElemment = focusableElements[elementPosition + 1];
        nextElemment.focus();
      }
      else if (elementPosition == focusableElements.length - 1) {
        // last element in the form
        focusableElements[elementPosition].blur();
      }
    }
  });
```